# Labeling cluttered vertices

Tags: plotting, graphics

I am trying to create a ConvexHullMesh plot where the vertices are labeled with their positions. I generate the ConvexHullMesh using

```
region = 
ConvexHullMesh[Join[pts1, pts2], Axes -> True, MeshCellStyle -> {1 -> Opacity[1, Red]}, 
MeshCellHighlight -> {2 -> Opacity[.3, Red]}, Frame -> False]
```

and then use

```
HighlightMesh[decompregion, Style[0, Directive[PointSize[0.015], Black]]]
```

to highlight the vertices. Which gives me this output:

[image]

Now I want to additionally see the positions of the vertices. The only thing I figured out yet, was `HighlightMesh[decompregion, Labeled[0, "Index"]]` which provides

[image]

First of all, I am not able to combine the `Labeled` and `Style` command. When I simply use `HighlightMesh[decompregion, Style[0, Directive[PointSize[0.015], Black]], Labeled[0, "Index"]]` I get an error.

Secondly I'd like to see the positions of the points and not their label. Is this possible?

And furthermore as you can see, since the vertices are cluttered one can barely read the labels. Is there some way of positioning the labels further away from the boundary and use some lines which indicate the corresponding point or some other smart solution to make it more readable? Increasing the plot size or being able to zoom in would be one step to improve it, however I also wasn't able to do that.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: The pts are extracted from a RegionPlot which is defined via a number of polynomial equations. I don't really think there is a benefit of posting all this code. You will face the same problem if you sample for example 200 points from the unit circle (  `pts = CirclePoints[200]`) and use the suggested code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pts = CirclePoints[200];

region = ConvexHullMesh[pts, Axes -> True, 
   MeshCellStyle -> {1 -> Opacity[1, Red]}, 
   MeshCellHighlight -> {2 -> Opacity[.3, Red]}, Frame -> False];
```

We can render the labels as custom [`Arrowheads`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Arrowheads.html):

```
mc = MeshCoordinates @ region;

Show[Graphics[{Arrowheads[{{.05, 1,
      {Graphics[Text[Style[Round[#, .01], 12, Black], 
       {0, 0}, {Left, Center}, {1, 0}]], .1}}}], 
  Thin, LightGray, Arrow[{#, # + .5 Normalize[# - RegionCentroid[region]]}]} & /@ mc],
  HighlightMesh[region, Style[0, Directive[AbsolutePointSize[7], Black]]],
 ImageSize -> 900, PlotRangeClipping -> False, ImagePadding -> Scaled[.05]]
```

[image]

Define `dir = {1, -1}/16`  and use

```
Arrow[{#, # + Last[dir = RotateLeft[dir]] Normalize[# - RegionCentroid[region]]}]
```

to get

[image]

Use `dir = {1/16, -1/16, 1/3, -1/3}` to get

[image]

Comment: Great. This is a big improvement. There are still labels overlapping when you are dealing with vertices where there is a big curvature, but for my purposes it is enough in most cases ( I have like 20 different convex hulls).

Comment: Thanks for your Edit! Now it works just fine

Answer (score 3):

```
pts1 = RandomReal[{}, {5, 2}];
pts2 = RandomReal[{}, {6, 2}];
region = ConvexHullMesh[Join[pts1, pts2], Axes -> True, 
   MeshCellStyle -> {1 -> Opacity[1, Red]}, 
   MeshCellHighlight -> {2 -> Opacity[.3, Red]}, Frame -> False];
BoundaryMeshRegion[region, 
 MeshCellLabel -> {All -> Placed["CellIndex", "Centroid"]}]
```

```
pts1 = RandomReal[{}, {5, 2}];
pts2 = RandomReal[{}, {6, 2}];
region = ConvexHullMesh[Join[pts1, pts2], Axes -> True, 
   MeshCellStyle -> {1 -> Opacity[1, Red]}, 
   MeshCellHighlight -> {2 -> Opacity[.3, Red]}, Frame -> False];
HighlightMesh[region, {Style[0, Directive[PointSize[0.015], Black]]}, 
 Epilog -> (Text[Round[#, .1], #] & /@ MeshCoordinates[region]), 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

```
pts1 = RandomReal[{}, {5, 2}];
pts2 = RandomReal[{}, {6, 2}];
region = ConvexHullMesh[Join[pts1, pts2], Axes -> True, 
   MeshCellStyle -> {1 -> Opacity[1, Red]}, 
   MeshCellHighlight -> {2 -> Opacity[.3, Red]}, Frame -> False];
HighlightMesh[region, {Style[0, Directive[PointSize[0.015], Black]], 
  Labeled[0, "CellIndex"]}]
```

```
pts1 = RandomReal[{}, {5, 2}];
pts2 = RandomReal[{}, {6, 2}];
region = ConvexHullMesh[Join[pts1, pts2], Axes -> True, 
   MeshCellStyle -> {1 -> Opacity[1, Red]}, 
   MeshCellHighlight -> {2 -> Opacity[.3, Red]}, Frame -> False];
HighlightMesh[region, {Style[0, Directive[PointSize[0.015], Black]]}, 
 MeshCellShapeFunction -> {1 -> (Arrow[#] &), 0 -> (Text[#, #] &)}]
```

```
pts1 = RandomReal[{}, {5, 2}];
pts2 = RandomReal[{}, {6, 2}];
region = ConvexHullMesh[Join[pts1, pts2], Axes -> True, 
   MeshCellStyle -> {1 -> Opacity[1, Red]}, 
   MeshCellHighlight -> {2 -> Opacity[.3, Red]}, Frame -> False];
HighlightMesh[region, {Style[0, Directive[PointSize[0.015], Black]], 
  Labeled[0, "Index"]}]
```

Comment: Using MeshCoordinates now basically does what I want. However the problem of readability is still there. Being able to zoom in/out would already be sufficient. Is there a way of doing so interactively without having to manually adjust the x/y range in the plot commands?

Answer (score 1):

This is addendum to cygnt's excellent answer. I thought the answer would be improved if we could see the regions the answer produced. On the other hand, I felt that it would too invasive to make such a large edit to cygnt's answer, especially since I have taken liberties with display style. I think my changes to that clarify the results.

```
SeedRandom[42]
pts1 = RandomReal[1, {5, 2}];
pts2 = RandomReal[1, {6, 2}];

region =
  ConvexHullMesh[Join[pts1, pts2],
    MeshCellStyle -> {1 -> Opacity[1, Red]}, 
    MeshCellHighlight -> {2 -> Opacity[.3, Red]}];

 BoundaryMeshRegion[region, 
  MeshCellLabel -> {All -> Placed["CellIndex", "Centroid"]},
  PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.08],
  Frame -> True]]
```

[image: r1]

```
HighlightMesh[region, {Style[0, Black]}, 
 Epilog -> (Text[Round[#, .1], #] & /@ MeshCoordinates[region]),
 PlotRangePadding -> {Scaled[.09], Automatic},
 Frame -> True]
```

[image: r5]

```
HighlightMesh[region,
  {Style[0, Directive[AbsolutePointSize[5], Black]],
   Labeled[0, "CellIndex"]},
  PlotRangePadding -> {Scaled[.1], Automatic},
  Frame -> True]
```

[image: r2]

```
HighlightMesh[region, {Style[0, Black, Opacity[1]]}, 
 MeshCellShapeFunction -> {1 -> (Arrow[#] &), 0 -> (Text[#, #] &)},
 PlotRangePadding -> {Scaled[.17], Scaled[.05]},
 Frame -> True]
```

[image: r3]

```
HighlightMesh[region,
  {Style[0, Directive[AbsolutePointSize[5], Black]], Labeled[0, "Index"]},
  PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05],
  Frame -> True]
```

[image: r4]

Comment: Thanks!  I am waiting an elegent solution which I cann't find. --- cvgmt :-)

Comment: Thanks for the edit. However, this only solves my question partly. When copy pasting the suggestions, the vertices are labeled with their coordinates. But unfortunately, the plots are still not useable, since the vertices are clustered which produces overlapping labels.